# Jenkinsfile copyArtifacts plugin: Use environment variable in filter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the Jenkins [copyArtifact](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) plugin installed and am using [declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) syntax.

I've set up my pipeline declaring environment variables as such:

```
pipeline {
        environment {
        ENVIRONMENT="prod"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to filter copying artifacts based on a filter determined by the environment variable specified above. However, when specifying the following in my declarative pipeline:

```
steps {
    copyArtifacts(
        filter: "build_${env.ENVIRONMENT}_*.exe"
    )
    // do stuff
    }
```

I get the following error:

`Failed to copy artifacts from feature/project with filter: build_${env.ENVIRONMENT}_*.exe`

The documentation indicates that "filter" is meant to be a string of syntax

> ant-expression to filter artifacts to copy

However I've been unable to integrate reading of pipeline environment variables in this filter parameter. Does anyone know if including environment variables in the filter string is possible? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Does this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed, but you would need to first **archive** before doing copy or should be available in the artifacts.
Example:

```
#!groovy
import hudson.model.Result
import groovy.json.*
pipeline 
{
    agent any   
    environment
            {
              ENVIRONMENT= "prod" 
            }
    stages 
    {
        stage ('stage 1')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                  // Example to show archiving of data. I Copy folder "MyArchive" to jenkins artifacts as an example.
                   dir("C:\\Data")
                  {
                      // Archive all files in folder "My_Archive"                 
                      archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: "My_Archive/"
                      copyArtifacts filter: "My_Archive/build_${env.ENVIRONMENT}_*.exe", fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Archivetest_Pipeline', selector: lastWithArtifacts(), target: 'C:\\Data\\Test'                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

You can also use the pipeline syntax generator to configure inputs as per your need.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator